# Is it possible to setup Eclipse code completion to show first party classes first

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to have the code completion in eclipse show my classes before other 3rd party classes (Always).

This means that if I write Region <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> it will show my first classes named Region from my projects packages first, and then all others

Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The order of Content Assists (Ctrl+Space) Class proposals depends of project Build Path.

You can modify with: Right click on project->Configure Build Path->Order and Export->And put your libs and src folder at top of the list.

Comment: I am working with maven. and its not a single project.. its like 5-6, but i would like that on all of them, when i Ctrl+Space i will see their classes before all the others

Comment: You must to do in every project. The order of classes who appear with Control+Space depends on project Build class path order.

Comment: Tried it in every possible combination in the build path. that really doesn't work. as well you cant change the order of the maven dependencies even if it was the solution.